# A transparent keyboard in Mobile Safari?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

How does one make a semi-opaque/transparent keyboard in Mobile Safari?

There seem to be a few solutions for doing this in native iOS apps in addition to UIWebViews, but not for keyboards instantiated in the stand-alone iOS web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the appearance of the system onscreen keyboard in Safari. You could create your own web browsing app that could do that but in Safari it isn't possible.